# ASP.NET website shows 503 Service Unavailable after successful publishing

Tags: asp.net, web, publishing, http-status-code-503

Every time I try to publish a website, it runs fine but when the website opens up it gives me a,

"HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable."

Everywhere I look on the internet talks about it being my application pool  but that seems to be running fine. I think it may be my web.config file but I'm not entirely sure.

PLEASE can someone help me.

"PICTURE OF ERROR BELOW"

[image]

Comment: How did you determine the application pool is running?

Comment: Because I have IIS Manager and the status of my Default App Pool is 'Started'

Comment: Could you add a `test.html` file to the website root and see if that file is available? (static files & compiled files may be handled differently)

Answer (score 4):

**Make absolute sure the App Pool is running**

Goto `WinKey+R` (`Start > Run`) type in `InetMgr`, press `enter`.
Left side, `Connections`, expand your computer or the server in question.
Select `Application pools`.
Start all pools that have their "Status" as `Stopped`.

**Make sure the site is set to the correct pool**

Not all sites are assigned to the default application pool, in this case, in the left side expand sites, find your site, expand it. In the right column, click `Basic configurations`.
Edit the application pool there, go back to the first block and make sure your newly assigned Application Pool is running.

**Test it**

Select your site again, In the right side, there is a `Browse site` group, click on `Browse *:80` (or something like that, this should do it).

**Check permissions on site's folder.**

Go to your site folder and give full permission to `NETWORK SERVICE`.

**Make sure Application Pool service is not disabled in windows services.**

If everything else fails, go to `Services.msc` and set the service related to your app pool to Automatic (maybe you or someone disabled it for some reason, who knows).

**Reinstall IIS**

Go to `Control panel > Programs and resources > Install Windows Resources`, find everything related to .NET, ASP.NET and install. Check all leftover boxes from IIS and subselects.
If this fails, uninstall it completely then install it again.

Let us know if any of these work.

Answer (score 1):

This is most times caused by **Application pool** which has been disabled or because the application pool identity is invalid.

- Go too **IIS** > **hostname** > **Application Pools** (Observe the Application is stopped)
- Right click and go to **Advance Settings**
- On **Identity** Select an Identity Pool from the drop-down list (possibly change the identity already selected by default)
- Restart the Application pool

To set up an Identity Pool to select from follow [this link](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213928785-Website-shows-503-Service-Unavailable-and-application-pool-crashing-An-account-failed-to-log-on)